# autofocus not working after remove and adding again to the dom

Tags: angular, angular-material

I trying to set focus on show:

```
<div>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%" (click)="inEdit=true">
    <div *ngIf="!inEdit">
      bla
    </div>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="inEdit">
      <input (blur)="inEdit=false" 
      autofocus matInput >
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

it is work only on first click.

[stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2d4ag?file=app/input-overview-example.html)

Comment: Strange.  It works on other clicks as long as you click inside the input field then click out of it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically call a focus method of HTML element whenever you need!

Try this:

Template:

```
<div>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="inEdit=true;focus()">Edit</button>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%" (click)="inEdit=true">
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="inEdit">
      <input #ref matInput >    
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {

  @ViewChild("ref",null) refField: ElementRef;

  focus(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.refField.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is due to the Angular Changedetection. So you have to wait until the next detection run. Just wrap "this.refField.nativeElement.focus()" in a setTimeout(). Like: setTimeout(() => {
      this.refField.nativeElement.focus();
    });

Comment: Modified the answer. Check

Comment: @SebastianMünster You are right.I wa doing the the same thing in stackbiltz

Comment: Ok, but there is no need to set a Timeout for 100ms. Just leave the time argument empty.

Comment: Ok, the solution is to do it in the setter:   `@ViewChild('ref') set refField(ref){
    if (!ref) return;
    ref.nativeElement.focus()
  }`

Comment: Thanks @yantrab :) . Didn't know about it.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Its always better to add some explanation to the answer, which helps to understand the code that you have written!

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve all DOM related operations in Angular using @ViewChild decorator whic comes from angular core.

**Related Template**

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" #inputName>
```

**Component :**

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit,ViewChild ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
... 

@ViewChild('inputName') inputEl:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus());
}
```

Using this ElementRef we can do dynamic DOM(Component) Rendering.

[**Note:**](http://%20https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/viewchildren-and-contentchildren/)

> Make sure before going to use ElememntRef,All DOM is rendered in local browser